# How do I make this Menu Bar

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

So I've been looking at this really cool menu bar that can that changes from a different vh.
(Link: https://forgecoaching.gg/)

I've been trying to code it now for over 3 days. Tried with some observers combined with some CSS keyframes and such

, and also a ScrollTrigger. I couldn't get it to work through.

I have taken an example in this code:
[How to show div again when scroll using vh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459922/how-to-show-div-again-when-scroll-using-vh)

But I can't seem to make it work.
Can someone explain to me?

Sry for the noob spirit, I am really new to javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the example in 'How To' of w3schools. It looks like the menu bar you want.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_slide.asp
Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
  background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
  top: -50px; /* Hide the navbar 50 px outside of the top view */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
}

/* Style the navbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
// When the user scrolls to the top of the page, slide up the navbar (50px out of the top view)
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Although the answer may indeed be helpful, it is of SO practice to post some outlines of an external link. The `quote` text formatting in the answer is exactly for that. Th reason is, the link may be dead, or edited, and your answer will be no longer relevant.